# How to access the site or database created by SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am going to install SharePoint server 2013 on the PC which is connected to LAN of my college. If I create a website or system on this PC using SharePoint Server 2013. How can I access this website from other PCs of the same LAN connection? Can users working on other desktops in the same LAN connection, access this data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes... If all your computers are connected via LAN it is possible.

Say for example.

One of your PC has SharePoint installed and its hostname is "sharepointserver" and its IP address "192.168.1.2".

Assuming, you have created on a web application and at least site collection at below URL

```
localhost:2101/sites/firstsitecollection
```

Other computer can access it via below 2 options

```
sharepointserver:2101/sites/firstsitecollection
192.168.1.2/sites/firstsitecollection
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will follow this access procedure once I create the website.. :)

Comment: Hi. I created a site using SharePoint. I tried the first option you mentioned and it showed the error as: SharePointserver refused to connect. Also, the second option asked me for username and password and after providing the same, it gives me an error "404 file not found". Hence I am not able to access the site using different computer. Please Help.